# Writing two variable in a root file in RootFramework

Tags: c++, graph, root-framework

I am new in root framework. I want to draw a graph for example; x vs. y graph. These values are related each other in a for loop.I get x values and y values for each x value. However, I could not save these variables in the same root file to draw a x vs. y graph, I could not find how can I do, because when I use TBrowser and use Draw option I get only a vs. bin graph.

Besides, I try to Fill option but it is needed a histogram, I guess I do not want to get histogram. I search Root Support, but I could not find a result for that there, also here.

Is there any suggestion to plot a graph with these two variables? Also, how can I save these variables in the same file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using TGraph class?
If you store x and y in some sort of array you can easily do something like this:

```
TGraph* graph=new TGraph(n,x,y); //where n is size of x and y arrays
TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas("c1","",0,0,600,600); 
graph->Draw("AP");
c1->Print("Graph.pdf"); //you can use different file format in output
```

That should create a pdf file with your graph. For saving your data you could use TNtuple or TTree. They have separate branches for each variable and the variable values are passed by giving the adress of variable in your program to the branch. Or you can just save it in the text file

[TGraph](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTGraph.html#aecf050cd2be96408a9ec172ee31137dc)

[TCanvas](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTCanvas.html)

Comment: Thank you! I could not find TVectorD graph in Tgraph, ,i realize now.